How to create a hyperlink to view the account record in an LWC where 10 account records are shown in 10 tiles with a hyperlink present in Account name
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Account Records">
        <ul>
            <template for:each={accounts} for:item="account">
                <li key={account.Id} style="padding: 10px">
                    <div class="demo-only" style="width:320px">
                        <ul class="slds-has-dividers_around-space">
                          <li class="slds-item">
                            <article class="slds-tile slds-tile_board">
                              <h3 class="slds-tile__title slds-truncate" title={account.Name}>
                                <a href={"/" + account.Id} target="_blank">{account.Name}</a>
                              </h3>
                              <div class="slds-tile__detail">
                                <p class="slds-text-heading_medium">{account.Phone}</p>
                                <p class="slds-truncate" title="Company One">
                                  <a href="#">{account.Industry}</a>
                                </p>
                              </div>
                            </article>
                          </li> 
                          </ul>
                    </div>  
                </li>
            </template>
        </ul>
    </lightning-card>
</template>


Please [edit] your post to include the specific error or issue with more details.

Since expressions (i.e. href={"/" + account.Id}) are not allowed in template, you need to add a property to the each account object holding the link to the right record page.
Keep in mind that any object privisioned by a wire adapter is immutable,
so if you retrieve those accounts via wired Apex method, you'll have to create a new instance of each object to be able to add a new property and you could leverage Array.map() to do so.
I.E.
@wire(getAccounts)
fetchAccounts({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
        this.accounts = data.map((elem) => {
            const account = { ...elem }; // Clone the original record to create a new instance
            account.href = `/lightning/r/Account/${account.Id}/view`;  // Add the computed property
            return account;
        });
    } else if (error) {
        console.error('fetchAccounts', error);
    }
}

Now in the template you could just reference the new property:
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Account Records">
        <ul>
            <template for:each={accounts} for:item="account">
                <li key={account.Id} style="padding: 10px">
                    <div class="demo-only" style="width:320px">
                        <ul class="slds-has-dividers_around-space">
                          <li class="slds-item">
                            <article class="slds-tile slds-tile_board">
                              <h3 class="slds-tile__title slds-truncate" title={account.Name}>
                                <a href={account.href} target="_blank">{account.Name}</a>
                              </h3>
                              <div class="slds-tile__detail">
                                <p class="slds-text-heading_medium">{account.Phone}</p>
                                <p class="slds-truncate" title="Company One">
                                  <a href="#">{account.Industry}</a>
                                </p>
                              </div>
                            </article>
                          </li> 
                          </ul>
                    </div>  
                </li>
            </template>
        </ul>
    </lightning-card>
</template


Thanks a lot..this worked for me
